# How do I get the schema name of the objects in the table "sys.all_objects?"

Tags: sql-server

How do I get the schema name of the objects in the table "sys.all_objects?"

Using the OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME function returns "sys" when I know the schema is dbo...

```
select OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id),* from sys.all_objects o
```

I don't want to use another view but I can join to other tables if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about system objects such as `sp_helptext`? You can call `sp_helptext` and other system objects using multiple formats and these are translated for you (mostly for backward compatibility reasons):

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_helptext';
EXEC dbo.sp_helptext 'sp_helptext';
EXEC sys.sp_helptext 'sp_helptext';

SELECT * FROM sysobjects;
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects;
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects;
```

But the object can only belong to one schema. In this case it is `sys` even if it answers to `dbo` as well.

If you have user objects that are showing up as `sys`, please let us know what they are. If you are just trying to track down user objects, perhaps you named something as `dbo.foo` that *also* exists under the `sys` schema. I might suggest `sys.objects` instead of `sys.all_objects` if you don't want to return system objects.

EDIT:

And as Ray pointed out, you are passing `schema_id` to the function. [The documentation shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx) you need to pass `object_id`, not `schema_id`. So either do one of the following:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.[object_id]),* FROM sys.all_objects o;

-- or

SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]),* FROM sys.all_objects o;
```

Personally, I prefer a join, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.name, o.* FROM sys.all_objects AS o;
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id];
```

Why? Because this query can work across databases, whereas several of the metadata functions will return NULL or - even worse - the wrong object when called from a different database.

Answer (score 3):

Use "object_id" not "schema_id"

`select OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id),* from sys.all_objects o`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id),* from sys.all_objects o
```

---

You can also select the column `name`:

```
select o.name,* from sys.all_objects o
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

select SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id),* from sys.all_objects o

But if you want my auto scripting version

insert into @tt (string)
select distinct 'GRANT execute ON SCHEMA :: '+SCHEMA_NAME(oo.schema_id)+' TO role_execute_all_sp'
from sys.all_objects oo 
where SCHEMA_NAME(oo.schema_id) not in ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA','sys')